# How to configure disk space in Ubunutu with SSD and HDD without dual boot?

Tags: ubuntu, hard-disk, ssd

I recently added an SSD (240 GB) to my laptop and installed Ubuntu on it. 
Since my HDD (1 TB – not external) wasn't being used, I mounted it at `/Disk`. 
Now I can't utilize the complete storage of the HDD.

P.S. I only want to use Ubuntu and don't plan on dual boot.

Can someone please suggest where I should mount the HDD
so that I can use the entire 1 TB?

As shown below, the available space in /Disk is 925GB however I can't use all this space since I only have 24GB free in root.

```
aman@achieve:~$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs           384M  2.1M  382M   1% /run
/dev/sdb2       219G  185G   24G  89% /
tmpfs           1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop0       28M   28M     0 100% /snap/chromium-ffmpeg/28
/dev/loop3       64M   64M     0 100% /snap/core20/1623
/dev/loop1      128K  128K     0 100% /snap/bare/5
/dev/loop2       19M   19M     0 100% /snap/chromium-ffmpeg/30
/dev/loop7       62M   62M     0 100% /snap/core20/1611
/dev/loop5       56M   56M     0 100% /snap/core18/2560
/dev/loop8       71M   71M     0 100% /snap/core22/188
/dev/loop4       71M   71M     0 100% /snap/core22/275
/dev/loop6       56M   56M     0 100% /snap/core18/2566
/dev/loop9      347M  347M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-38-2004/115
/dev/loop13     348M  348M     0 100% /snap/telegram-desktop/4208
/dev/loop18     175M  175M     0 100% /snap/opera/199
/dev/loop11     141M  141M     0 100% /snap/skype/226
/dev/loop10      46M   46M     0 100% /snap/snap-store/592
/dev/loop20      65M   65M     0 100% /snap/sublime-text/112
/dev/loop19      92M   92M     0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535
/dev/loop17      55M   55M     0 100% /snap/snap-store/558
/dev/loop12     174M  174M     0 100% /snap/opera/198
/dev/loop15      47M   47M     0 100% /snap/snapd/16292
/dev/loop16     165M  165M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/161
/dev/loop14     251M  251M     0 100% /snap/zoom-client/170
/dev/loop21     346M  346M     0 100% /snap/telegram-desktop/4116
/dev/loop24      66M   66M     0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1519
/dev/loop23      48M   48M     0 100% /snap/snapd/16778
/dev/loop22     401M  401M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-38-2004/112
/dev/loop26     147M  147M     0 100% /snap/qbittorrent-arnatious/86
/dev/loop25     296M  296M     0 100% /snap/vlc/2344
/dev/sdb1       511M  5.3M  506M   2% /boot/efi
/dev/sda1       932G  6.6G  925G   1% /Disk
tmpfs           384M   44K  384M   1% /run/user/1000
```

Comment: I don't understand. Why can't you use `/home/Disk`? What do you want to use it for? Just store whatever you want in `/home/Disk` if that's where you want to have it. Please [edit] your question and explain the problem in more detail.

Comment: You need to give us the partition table on the HDD to show why the entire disk is not being utilized. Edit your question with the output of `fdisk -l`. Also, do you want this space specifically allocated to a single directory tree or should the entire disk be mounted as `/home`?

Comment: I have edited the question to show my disk usage.

Comment: I would lilke to use this space specifically allocated to a single directory tree.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your use of the second hard disk. Usually, I choose one of these 3 methods (when I add an additional disk):

- It will point to /home/ (Note as root, you should rename old /home/, mount the new home, and move the home accounts there. Then restart and you should be in the new home (and only at this point can you delete the renamed home). Why? Because often /home/ is using most of the space (the rest remain nearly constant)
- I will create a /pub and some directories like home with just specific users, and others with groups and general use). So git, large files, sources, virtual machines, etc. Often I point websites and databases to there (so either pointing directly or moving the data here, and then a symlink from /var/lib/*sql and /var/www)
- Seldom I do the same as the first point, but with /var/ or better just /var/lib or just /var/lib/*sql (mostly if I have some huge databases or logs to keep). Moving this may be tricky (because of lock files, etc.). Logging directly as root and with single-user mode helps (or a rescue disk is better). Note: ev. create a /var/pub and a symlink from /pub if I have soo much space I can use for useful things.

So, it depends on how you plan to use the extra space. In early times I moved often directories, but you discover subtle bugs, and now some directories must no more be mounted in a separated (from root) filesystem, like /usr.

Comment: Hello,
Thank you for your reply. Even if I do rename my /home, I don't think I will be able to use the entire 1TB space since it will be limited by the 240GB constraint of SSD. I have edit my question to show the disk usage. That should help clear the picture. 
Please feel free to correct me if I am wrong. Thanks again!